# "desinat igitur gloriando etiam insectari dolores nostros."

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, gerund

In Cicero *Letters to Brutus* [we find](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0007%3Abook%3D1%3Aletter%3D17%3Asection%3D5):

> desinat igitur gloriando etiam insectari dolores nostros.

Two questions:

1. Is *gloriando* here connects with *desinat* or with *insectari*. In other words, what would be accurate transtlation: "Let him stop boasting and speak ill(?) of our grieves"; or, "let him stop speaking ill of our grieves *by* boasting. Leob translation, which does not help me decide, reads:

> So let him stop his boasting which is an aggravation of our distresses.

I would generally lean towards the second option (as the follow-up question demonstrates), but then what is this *etiam* which seems to be lost in translation (or else you read *insectari dolores* as "apposition" to *gloriando*?)

2. General question independent of (1), can we connect *desino* with abl. gerund (or even gen. gerund) to have the same meaning like the infinitive? e.g., "*desino optando*" pretty much like the English "stop hoping"? My limited corpus search yielded only this verse from Cicero as a candidate.

---

**Edit**:

I could find [another translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0007:book=1:letter=17)(Evelyn Shuckburgh, Evelyn S. Shuckburgh, 1908) which thankfully uses *by*, but, again, how is *etiam* rendered?:

> Let him cease then from absolutely insulting our misfortunes by his boastful language

Answer (score 4):

Lewis & Short, while often obstinately unhelpful to people who just want to figure out the meaning of a word at a glance, usually has [copious usage examples](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=desino). In this case, you can see *desino* goes with an infinitive or a direct object in the accusative.
In your sentence, *insectari* must be the argument to *desinat*, and *gloriando* can only be a satellite—specifically, as you've figured out, it's an instrumental: "by boasting".

For your second question, Shuckburgh either hasn't translated the *etiam* (unless it went into his "then" along with *igitur*) or reflected it as that "absolutely", which I don't think is defensible. Use translations to guide you into seeing structure in the Latin, not as absolute authorities in their own right.

Comment: I see. For the translations, I specifically used them as a guide, but none has really convinced me; for I still don't understand what is the *meaning* of *etiam* if we accept the instrumental *gloriando*.

Comment: *Lexicis [contingit], quod mulierculis, cum diu in eas invecti sunt viri, ultro ad eas supplicatum veniunt, et commoditatibus illarum uti gaudent* ([Io. Matthias Gesnerus](http://mateo.uni-mannheim.de/camenaref/gesner/gesner1/v1/jpg/as0009.html))

Comment: A couple of minor points: (1) the term "satellite" is not so widespread as that of "adjunct" (I think that "satellite" is only (?) used by functional linguists: e.g. Dik, Pinkster, et al.). Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar); (2) I would not recommend to "use translations to guide one into seeing (syntactic) structure in the Latin". (Good) translations must respect content/meaning and information structure of the source text but may have a different syntactic structure.

Comment: @Mitomino, the irony is (as I see that), that this is exactly when one acknowledges that "translations must respect content/meaning and information structure of the source text but may have a different syntactic structure", that he is then ripe to read back into the Latin and seeing the syntactic structure of the Latin. For, after all, different grammatical understanding of a sentence results in different meanings. For my experience at least, translation were very helpful getting the structure of the Latin.

Comment: @d_e I agree that translations can be helpful when learning Latin syntax but one should be cautious. E.g., consider this very typical text: _Gallia est omnis divisa in partes tres, quarum unam incolunt Belgae, ..._ 'Gaul is a whole divided into three parts, one of which is inhabited by the Belgae' (Loeb). Note that a very natural way to translate a **rhematic subject** like _Belgae_ into English involves using a _**by**_-phrase. Good translations can sacrifice syntactic structure (even in radical aspects: e.g. from active to passive) to preserve information structure. Hence my caveat above.